# Magento 2 load very slowly after changing less file

Tags: performance, compilation, less, magento2, magento-2.0

I'm trying to create new theme. But every time I reload the home page it is going to high CPU loading.

My Settings:
**New theme has just one file**: /app/design/frontend/Test/default/web/css/source/_extend.less
**Magento mode**: developer
**Front-end development workflow**: Server-side less compilation
**Grunt**: installed and configured.

Activity monitor:

[image: Mac os activity monitor]

Chrome console:

[image]

And only after `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` the page is loading fast:

[image]

Do I need to deploy static content every time I change some css style if I develop new theme?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,You Have to load static content every Time whenever you do changes in css or js files,magento loads files only from cache,so even if you have done small change you have to deploy it so thet magento can load the changes on website